# Android ADT Debugging Hangs Attempting to connect to debugger on port 8601?

Tags: android, debugging

The app runs fine, but it hangs when attempting to connect the debugger, using Eclipse ADT plugin.  Sometime shutting down the device will allow debugging to run again.  What are the possible reasons for this. I have breakpoints in every create on every activity.  What could be the problem?  What is it really waiting for?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, only I hadn't realized some eclipse processes were still running since there were no more eclipse windows open.... Check for eclipse.exe as well as javax.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like this might have been related to having more than once instance of eclipse running.  I separate instance running for separate workspace.  Closing on instance appears to have fixed it in this case.  might also need to set android:debuggable="true" in application element of manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just have to reboot your Android device.
I have frequent issues with Eclipse, too.

Order I reset:

1. Disconnect USB, reconnect.
2. On Android Device, disconnect USB Debugging, reconnect.
3. Restart adb - In Eclipse go to DDMS screen, select the down arrow next to the camera and     select 'reset adb'
4. Reboot Android Device (for constant problem with debug connecting)
5. Reboot PC (generally doesn't help)

Answer (score 0):

Do not select any video source (your webcam), just let it empty when the application ask you to select one of them.

Comment: The way you use "let" and "it" leaves your answer somewhat unclear.  Does "it" mean a prompt for a video source, i.e. "just leave the prompt for video source empty"?  If so, what do you do next?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i attempted to debug a unit test by starting it from the junit view (right click -> debug as...) which failed and displayed the error message "Test launch failed due to internal error: Running tests on UI thread".

This was due to this bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34170

The fix for me was to not run from the junit view, but rather run from the debug button on the toolbar.

I'm using ADT 20.

Answer (score 0):

My solution - works with "Windows 8 Pro 64-bit", "Google Nexus" and "Android Developer Tools Build: v21.1.0-569685"

1. Close any Eclipse instance.
2. Ensure no application is listening on port 8061, you can use: NETSTAT -B in Windows command line to list all ports listened by applications. Sometimes, adb.exe or javaw.exe are still listening on 8061 port, even you think Eclipse is closed.
3. Close javaw.exe, adb.exe until 8061 port is free.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have probably figured this out in 4 years, but I am so happy after I found the problem that I want to someone to know about it.

For me there was a breakpoint on variable declaration in MainActivity Class. This variable declaration wasn't a part of any method and the statement itself was never executing. And there was no other breakpoint in entire application. Once I put the breakpoint at correct location (onClick method), everything fell into place.

Don't know if this worked for you.